# How do I pass arguments in graphql query

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo-client

```js
export const GET_ALL_CLUSTERS_STATUS = gql`
query MyQuery {
  status(arg: {aws_client_key_id: String, aws_client_secret: String}) {
    data
  }
}
`
```

```js
const { loading, data, error } = useQuery(GET_ALL_CLUSTERS_STATUS, {
    variables: {aws_client_key_id:"SOMEKEY", aws_client_secret: "SOMESECRET"}
  });
```

I am getting undefined there's something wrong in my 2nd code but can't find it on docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify what parameters to expect

```
query MyQuery($aws_client_key_id: String!, $aws_client_secret: String!) {
  status(arg: {aws_client_key_id: $aws_client_key_id, aws_client_secret: $aws_client_secret}) {
    data
  }
}
```